# In JSON request body, how do I know if a field value is missing or value is explicitly set to null?

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

`PersonController.java`

```
@PutMapping(value = "/update", produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public PersonDTO update (HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody @Valid PersonDTO person) {
        return service.update(person);
    }
```

`Person.DTO`

```
public class PersonDTO {
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    private Integer age;

    @JsonProperty("hobbies")
    private String hobbies;

}
```

My Request body looks like this

```
{
      "name": "Dinesh",
      "age": 25
}
```

If I don't pass `hobbies` in my dtom I see the value as null.
I want to update my database only when `hobbies` is being passed.
In some cases, I pass `hobbies` in my request to set to NULL.
In the previous case I don't want to update my hobbies column in the database.
How do I differentiate these two?

Answer (score 0):

Update PersonController.java as,

```
@PutMapping(value = "/update", produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public PersonDTO update (HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody @Valid Map<String,Object> person) {

   if(!person.containsKey("hobbies")) {
       // Logic in case hobbies is NOT passed by user
   } else if (person.containsKey("hobbies") && person.get("hobbies") == null){
       // Logic in case hobbies is passed by user as NULL
   } else {
       //Logic when hobbies is passed by the user
   }
   return service.update(person);
}
```

I hope this helps.